# Linq transforming parent list of sub lists to be grouped by sub list entities

Tags: linq, .net-core, data-transform

Sorry for this unclear title, but im not sure how to name it. It will be easier to just show it:

**Objects example:**

```
class Order
  {
     public string OrderNumber{ get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<ProductWithQuantity> ProductsWithQuantities{ get; set; }
  }

class ProductWithQuantity
  {
     public string ProductName{ get; set; }
     public int Quantity{ get; set; }
  }
```

Lets say i have `IEnumerable<Order>` and every order has list of products together with quantity. Orders always have the same list of products, just diffrent quantities. Right now its all grouped by orders, how to reverse it to be grouped by products.

To better visualize it, i will show what i want to achieve on pseudo jsons.

**Current json generated:**

```
[
    {
        OrderNumber,
        ProductsWithQuantities [
            {ProductName, Quantity}
        ]
    }
]
```

**And i want to achieve something like this:**

```
[
    {
        ProductName,
        OrdersWithQuantities [
            {OrderNumber, Quantity}
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried to use select and group by but i can't work it out.

Comment: for old situation you have grouped by ``OrderNumber`` and now you will group by ``productName``?

Comment: Correct. Its like data taken from excel where you have list of ProductNames to the left, and each column is order. At the intersection of each row (product) and column (order) there is quantity. Structure of data taken from excel is based on columns but now i need to convert it to be based on rows (inital structure cannot be changed).

Comment: i have proposed an answer, can you check it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - By considering the following collection of test:

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>
{
    new Order
    {
        OrderNumber = "o1",
        ProductsWithQuantities = new List<ProductWithQuantity>
        {
            new ProductWithQuantity{ProductName = "p1", Quantity=1},
            new ProductWithQuantity{ProductName = "p2", Quantity=2},
        }
    },
    new Order
    {
        OrderNumber = "o2",
        ProductsWithQuantities = new List<ProductWithQuantity>
        {
            new ProductWithQuantity{ProductName = "p1", Quantity=1},
            new ProductWithQuantity{ProductName = "p2", Quantity=2},
        }
    }
};
```

2 - You can use `SelectManay` to flatten all product. and group by `ProductName` by building new collection, like the following code:

```
var result = orders
    .SelectMany(x => x.ProductsWithQuantities.Select(y => new { x.OrderNumber, y.ProductName, y.Quantity }))
    .GroupBy(p => p.ProductName)
    .Select(x => new 
        { 
            ProductName = x.Key, 
            OrderWithQuantities = x.Select(y => new { OrderNumer = y.OrderNumber, Quantity = y.Quantity }).ToList() 
        })
    .ToList();
```

3 - Demo

```
foreach(var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.ProductName} : " +
        $"{string.Join(",", item.OrderWithQuantities.Select(x => $"{x.OrderNumer}::{x.Quantity}"))}");
}
```

4 - Result:

```
p1 : o1::1,o2::1
p2 : o1::2,o2::2
```

I hope this help.